# Salesforce Communities: Shorten {!Community_Url}

Tags: community, email, customer-community

Is there any way to shorten the merge field {!Community_Url} when a welcome email (default or custom) is sent from a community?  The Community URL in the email looks like spam and I want to shorten it to make it more aesthetically pleasing as well as less spammy.

I tried using LinkForce to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The way I actually solved this (even though Bob Lopez's answer is also great!) is by using the hyperlink button and putting the merge field in there.

So it looked something like [THIS](http://%7B!Community_Url%7D)

I felt really silly once I stumbled upon this solution but it makes sense and more importantly it works! I always thought hyperlink texts needed an actual merge field and wouldn't accept merge fields. I was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an HTML Email Template and use a simple `<a>` element to create a hyperlink with whatever text you want to display to the user.

Example:

```
<a href="{!Community_Url}">Welcome Text</a>
```

Comment: Hi Bob - when I try entering the HTML code for <a>, instead of being parsed as a link, the code is getting embedded in the body of the email as a string. Is there any specific setting to turn this off? Thanks.

Comment: @miCRoSCoPiC_eaRthLinG are you using a text email template or an html email template?